# MLE of $\frac{e^{-\frac{|x-\theta|}{2}}}{2\sqrt{2\pi|x-\theta|}}$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

I am starting to learn more advanced statistics and I have come across this problem:
Find the Maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ if $X_i$ have the following density:
$f(x-\theta)$
with $f(x-\theta)=\frac{e^{\frac{-|x-\theta|}{2}}}{2\sqrt{2\pi|x-\theta|}}$
I have tried to differentiate the log but cannot find where it is equal to zero.
<\br> What I have so far:
$$
V_{X_1,...,X_n}(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(X_i-\theta)
$$
$$
\log(V_{X_1,...,X_n}(\theta))=(\sum_{i=1}^n-\frac{|X_i-\theta|}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\log(|X_i-\theta|))-n\log(2\sqrt{2\pi})
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\log(V_{X_1,...,X_n}(\theta))}{\partial\theta}=\sum_{i=1}^n-\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{1}_{\theta>X_i}-\boldsymbol{1}_{\theta\leq X_i})-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{|X_i-\theta|}
$$

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you show us your work, what you tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: Part of the reason for your difficulty is that you don't have a $\theta$ anywhere in your expression for $f(x)$.  You need one in order to be able to differentiate the log with respect to it.

Comment: jbowman is correct, but you should also (a) check that you have correctly specified a density and (b) beware differentiating without checking it's differentiable. That may alter your strategy.

Comment: @jbowman Yeah it is supposed to be (implicitely) f(x-theta) as indicated above, f(x) is the general function but the density is f(x-theta)

Comment: You can actually solve this w/o calculus; just stare at that denominator for a while, imagine what it would take to make it as small as possible, and see what value the numerator has at that point.  Draw your conclusions from that...

Comment: Draw a plot with an artificial sample to understand the shape of the likelihood function.

Comment: @Xi'an It seems that the average of all Xs could work but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: @Sir_Joan_the_third thanks for showing your work mon pot. The mean is a good guess because that tends to be the answer to statistical questions. But set aside your stats knowledge for a moment and forget about taking logarithmic derivatives. Rewrite your density as $\frac{1}{|x-\theta|} c(x)$, where $c(x)$ has absorbed the remaining terms (and you can show that it is bounded). What happens when $x\to\theta$?

Comment: (oh I meant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-\theta|}}c(x)$, but this doesn't change anything)

Comment: The case with $n=2$ *iid* samples $x_1,$ $x_2$ is illustrative and easy to work out.  The likelihood is a product of two functions of $\theta,$ one of which blows up at $x_1$ and the other of which blows up at $x_2.$  Where, then, are the places where the likelihood is maximized?

Comment: @JohnMadden I think I see, so MLE is equal to any Xi?

Comment: @Sir_Joan_the_third exactment :) this likelihood violates the assumptions one usually makes when conducting MLE, so this would be a poor estimation technique, as the absurdity of the optimizing set shows.